# Device eth0 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization

Tags: networking, interface, centos

i am using mellanox network card, everyday in the morning when i start the server, there is an error trying to make a bad day, that is "Device eth0 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization".

when i reboot the server, nothing happen. Error continues. but when i completely poweroff my machine and then start it again, the network card goes up normally.

i tried each and every solution that i was able to find on google. i deleted "70-persistent-net" file, i removed Hardware address from Ifcfg-eth0 file, i used commands like start_udev, depmod, modprobe, but the problem continues.

can anybody please tell  me any other soltuion other than poweroff.

## I am using CentOS 6.5

Answer (score 0):

Do you have just one NIC?

And, check the DEVICE=eth0 at ifcfg-eth0.
(error occurs if other. ie "eth1".)

Comment: Yeah Jinil, its all right. Device=eth0 not eth1.  Actually everything is ok. i am using two NIC.

Comment: How about check NIC's driver?

Comment: yeah buddy, the time when this problem spoil my morning, NIC drivers not loaded into kernel. no matter how many times i restart my PC, no matter how many and what kind of commands i pass, problem remain same. but when i completely shut down my machine and start it again, driver loaded and everything is fine.